# How do I find the standard matrix for this weird linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm lost on determining the matrix for this linear transformation. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

> $$\mathbb{R}[X]_{[\leq3]} \to \mathbb{R}$$
>   $$f = a_3X^3 + a_2X^2 + a_1X + a_0 \mapsto f(x)=a_3c^3 + a_2c^2 + a_1c + a_0$$
>
> Evaluating polynomials at $0,1,2,3$, we get a linear map $\Phi : \mathbb{R}[X]_{[\leq3]}\to\mathbb{R}^4$ defined by
>
> $$\Phi : \mathbb{R}[X]_{[\leq3]}\ni f \mapsto
>  \begin{pmatrix}
>   f(0) \\
>   f(1) \\
>   f(2) \\
>   f(3) \\
>  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^4$$
>
> **Question:**
>
> Give the matrix expression $A_\Phi$ of $\Phi$ with respect to the basis $B=\{1,X,X^2,X^3\}$ of $\mathbb{R}[X]_{[\leq3]}$ and the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I am having trouble understanding how to approach this problem and I am looking for some hints in where to begin.

EDIT: Would the matrix look something like this?
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8\\
1 & 3 & 9 & 27\\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: What is $c$ in the definition of $f$?

Comment: @amd Just a scalar constant. The question was a little long, so I tried to cut out some stuff.

Comment: So the map $f$ is just the linear functional “evaluate at $c$?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linear transformation $\Phi$ is represented by a $4\times4$-matrix. Its columns are the images of the basis vectors $1$, $X$, $X^2$, $X^3$ under $\Phi$. So; what column vectors in $\Bbb{R}^4$ are these basis vectors mapped to?

Comment: Would the matrix look like the one I edited in above?

Comment: That's exactly right.